# Fill values in month columns based on start and enddate in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below,

```
startdate    ||enddate   ||price|| jan|| feb|| mar

2015-12-23   2017-01-31    223.3

2015-01-01   2017-03-31     1.9

2017-02-03   2017-03-23     5.99

2017-02-01   2017-02-23     233
```

I have to fill the month columns(jan,feb,mar) with same value in 'Price' column,based on the start and end date.

eg. incase if current month=jan
current year=2017

1)  year(startdate)=2015, month(endate)=jan
then fill price value only in [jan] column not in other columns

2)   year(startdate)=2015,month(enddate)=mar
then fill price value in [jan],[feb],[mar]

eg. incase if current month=Feb
current year=2017

1) year(startdate)=2017,if month(startdate)=feb and month(endaate)=mar
then fill [feb] and [mar] alone, not for [jan]

2) year(startdate)=2017,month(startdate)=feb,month(endate)=feb
fill only for [feb]

Comment: Which database platform are you using?

Comment: I'm not following your logic, please add your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this :

```
UPDATE
    table_Name
SET 
  jan = CASE WHEN DATEPART(yyyy, startdate) = DATEPART(yyyy, enddate) 
                  AND 
                  DATEPART(mm, startdate) <= 01  AND DATEPART(mm, endate) >= 01 
             THEN `price` 
             WHEN DATEPART(yyyy, startdate) != DATEPART(yyyy, enddate)
                  AND
                  DATEPART(mm, enddate) >= 01
             THEN `price`
             ELSE NULL END,
  feb = CASE WHEN DATEPART(yyyy, startdate) = DATEPART(yyyy, enddate) 
                  AND 
                  DATEPART(mm, startdate) <= 02  AND DATEPART(mm, endate) >= 02
             THEN `price` 
             WHEN DATEPART(yyyy, startdate) != DATEPART(yyyy, enddate)
                  AND
                  DATEPART(mm, enddate) >= 02
             THEN `price`
             ELSE NULL END;
```

I have only written code for first two months you can do the rest by replacing the numbers in query with month number.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` expressions for each of your month columns:

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate, Price, 
 CASE WHEN {some condition = true} THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS Jan,
 CASE WHEN {some condition = true} THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS Feb,
 CASE WHEN {some condition = true} THEN Price ELSE NULL END AS Mar,
 ...etc...
```